# How to do a Markov process that generates "loopable" sequences?

Tags: markov-process

I have a data set of sequential events that I could train a higher order Markov model on so that it generates sequences of events that are similar to the input set.

The properties of the generated sequence I am looking for:

- it is finite
- it needs to be "loopable", meaning that the transition from the last event to the first event must follow the transition probabilities of the model

I know this makes it a whole different beast from a simple Markov process.

**What are good ways to solve this?**

Does a problem like this perhaps already have a good name I could google for? (I did try things like "Markov chain constraints" but it mostly leads me to scientificy papers that take me a lot of time to understand if they even try to address my specific problem.)

Comment: It isn't clear to me what you mean by "loopable" and how this differs from a plain old Markov chain (whether it's first order or of some higher order). Could you clarify?

Comment: @Adrian Does the 2nd bullet point not explain it? So the last event not only depends on earlier events, but the transition lastEvent -> firstEvent should match the transition probabilities.

Comment: The looping structure means that it's no longer a Bayesian network and cannot be fitted with simple belief propagation. Some keywords to guide your search are "loopy belief propagation", "Markov random fields", and "factor graphs".